# Generating Gaussian random numbers with restrictions

Tags: statistics

I want to generate a set of random numbers from N(M,S). with the following restrictions:
1. every sample x be greater than a constant c.
2. the error between sample mean and M be at most e1. 
3. the error between sample std and S be at most e2. 
How can a obtain a set of samples with these characteristics.

Comment: did you tried to use acceptance-rejection technique?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution ?

Comment: @pointguard0 I dont know the technique you mentioned; however, as the mentioned errors should be small, and I require a set of samples, like 1000; simple heuristics may be inapplicable

Comment: for general like to the technique please take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). What I mean is every time that you generate a r.v. from $\mathcal{N}(M, S)$ and it doesn't satisfy given three conditions you simply ignore that value. You repeat this until get 1000 samples satisfying your conditions.